# How to insert a space after a substitution of a variable or a command?

Tags: spacing, macros

I am trying to learn how to define **commands** `(\newcommand`) and **variables** `(\def)` in LaTeX.

When I try:

```
\def \new {$new$}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\new}{$new$}
```

and substitute it in the text:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\def \new {$new$}           
%\newcommand{\new}{$new$}

\begin{document}
lala \new lala
\end{document}
```

The substituted text sticks to the following text as shown here:

[image]

no matter how many spaces I put after the command.

What causes this behavior and how can I change it?

Comment: That's the normal behaviour. Any amount of space after a *control sequence* (such as `\new`) gets gobbled. To effect a space after `\new`, you can, for instance, use an empty group `{}`: try `lala \new{} lala`.

Comment: Or use `xspace` package and put `\newcommand{\new}{$new$\xspace}`. David is here any way to help ;-)